# Asking datasource credentials

Tags: reporting-services, datasource, ssrs-2008-r2, rdl

[image]I have created one report and the `.rdl` file is uploaded to report server from another machine. But when running the report it is asking for data source credentials. Can we avoid asking data source credentials while running report?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go into Manage and then into data sources, enter the desired credentials and save. it will store them in the reports server and will not ask again.

Comment: is there a way to do this programmatically?